# SQL: Which is faster for finding a relative date, d, m, or neither?

Tags: sql

I'm pulling data that's, say, a week back. Which query would execute faster:

```
WHERE
ev.EVENT_DATE >= DATEADD(d, -7, GETDATE())
```

OR

```
ev.EVENT_DATE >= DATEADD(wk, -1, GETDATE())
```

---

Or for a month:

```
ev.EVENT_DATE >= DATEADD(d, -30, GETDATE())
```

OR

```
ev.EVENT_DATE >= DATEADD(wk, -4, GETDATE())
```

OR

```
ev.EVENT_DATE >= DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE())
```

Is it easier/faster to compare the limited range of month values than the larger range of weeks or each individual day?

Comment: Your three queries for "one month back" all give different results in the majority of cases (1 and 2 do in all cases), so the "right" choice depends on how you define "one month ago". I would not expect any significant performance difference between calculating 1 week and 7 days ago.

Comment: all should be relatively similar but run a few tests to see.  The largest issue is your Month assumption.  The only 1 that will ensure you get data from last month is DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE()).  Because there can be 28,29,31, or 30 days in a month and because there can be 5 weeks in a month....

Comment: Suppose there is a difference in performance, how would you estimate its scale? hours? minutes? seconds? milliseconds? microseconds?

Comment: `GETDATE()` is a runtime constant, so each in each query the `DATEADD` expression is calculated once at run time, and a constant value used in the query. There will be no significant, or consistent difference between the various methods. The variance will be in microseconds, and will be to do with other factors, and not the argument passed to `DATEADD`.